# Trying to correct Github's Linguist

Tags: git, github, github-linguist

Like many programmers, I use Github for version control. However, my websites which I made with ASP.NET list as PowerShell repos when there's little to no PowerShell involved. I'm trying to fix this by adding

```
*.rb linguist-language=CSharp
```

to the .gitattributes file but it isn't taking as it still lists as a PowerShell repo. How can I fix this?

Note: I also tried C# instead of CSharp. Still nothing

https://github.com/nickgilbert1994/Covenant-Tech-Club-Website/blob/master/.gitattributes

Comment: The repo you linked has 67.0% PowerShell according to GitHub's stats.

Comment: (Answering the question of how to find statistics:) Go to the repo's main page and click the colored bar below the commits, branch,releases & contributor info. The one that says "Click for language details" when hovering.

Comment: Ah I see what happened, Visual Studio made publishing scripts with PowerShell. So I can't change the language at all then?

Comment: I don't know actually, see if someone else posts an answer. I only commented because you wrote "there's little to no PowerShell involved" which was blatantly untrue. =)

Comment: Figured it out. *rb is ruby's file extension...I'm an idiot

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Linguist to ignore Powershell files:

```
*.ps1 linguist-vendored
```